# default state in nested ui-view in ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am working on a project where I have a created a directive for a multi step form. Essentially trying to replicate [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router#nested-form-views-formprofilehtml-forminterestshtml-formpaymenthtml). The project layout has a header,navigation, a content page (which includes a ui-view) depending on the tab selected on the navigation tab.

Now there is a form tab which when clicked routes to a HTML page which includes this form directive. The directive calls the template (which includes another ui-view) loads the html content but failed to load the nested state. How do I set the default state?

The project directory looks like

```
src
   main
       app
          directive
                  formData
                          formData.js
                          formData.tpl.html
                          formInterest.tpl.html
                          formProfile.tpl.html
                          formFinal.tpl.html
          views
               header.html
               leftNavigation.html
               appRun.html
          app.js
          index.html
```

The app.js file has states defined as

```
$stateProvider
        .state('landingPage', {
            url: '/landingPage',
            templateUrl: 'views/landingPage.html'
        })
        .state('appRun', {
            url: '/appRun',
            templateUrl: 'views/appRun.html'
        })
        .state('appRun.first', {
            url: '/first',
            templateUrl: 'directives/formData/formProfile.tpl.html'
        })
        .state('appRun.second', {
            url: '/second',
            templateUrl: 'directives/formData/formInterest.tpl.html'
        })
        .state('appRun.third', {
            url: '/third',
            templateUrl: 'directives/formData/formFinal.tpl.html'
        });
```

The appRun.html looks like

```
<form-data></form-data>
```

The formData.js directive looks like

```
var formData = angular.module('formData',[]);

formData.directive('formData',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        replace: true,
        link: function($scope, element, attributes){

        },
        controller: function($scope,$attrs,$http){

            $scope.processForm = function(){
                console.log("processFrom");
            }
        },
        templateUrl: 'directives/formData/formData.tpl.html'
    }
});
```

the formData.tpl.html looks like

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

        <div id="form-container">

            <div class="page-header text-center">
                <h2>Let's Be Friends</h2>

                <!-- the links to our nested states using relative paths -->
                <!-- add the active class if the state matches our ui-sref -->
                <div id="status-buttons" class="text-center">
                    <a ui-sref-active="active"  ui-sref=".first"><span>1</span> Profile</a>
                    <a ui-sref-active="active"  ui-sref=".second"><span>2</span> Interests</a>
                    <a ui-sref-active="active"  ui-sref=".third"><span>3</span> final</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- use ng-submit to catch the form submission and use our Angular function -->
            <form id="signup-form" ng-submit="processForm()">

                <!-- our nested state views will be injected here -->
                <div  ui-view></div>


            </form>

        </div>

        <!-- show our formData as it is being typed -->
        <pre>
            {{ formData }}
        </pre>


    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on appRun state it shows up the content in formData.html but ui-view doesn't show a default state. How do I add a default state such that when the formData.html is loaded it also shows appRun.first state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<ng-include="'directives/formData/formProfile.tpl.html'"/>
```

Inside `<div ui-view></div>`. This will be the default page.

The other option:

1. Mark state `appRun` abstract.
2. Whenever linking to `appRun` link to `appRun.first` instead.

Comment: i followed the second approach by making abstract. thanks